# Idiomatic way to compare to nullptr: if(p) vs if (p != nullptr)

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

What is the idiomatic way of comparing a pointer to `nullptr`?

```
if (ptr) ...
if (!ptr) ...
```

or

```
if (ptr != nullptr) ...
```

I know both are equivalent, but which is preferable?

Personally I find the first version easier to read. But with the implicit conversion from the `0` literal to `nullptr` no longer being considered idiomatic (say for initialization), I wonder if the same is true for the implicit conversion of a pointer to `bool`.

Is there any objective reason to prefer one over the other?

As an analogy, consider a function `void foo(void*)`. Here, calling `foo(nullptr)` instead of relying on the implicit conversion `foo(0)` is better, because the latter breaks once we add an overload of `void foo(int)`.

Comment: What do you mean by *implicit conversion from the `0` literal to `nullptr` no longer being considered idiomatic*?

Comment: `if (ptr)` is well defined and in the standard.  It is safe to use.

Comment: That you should prefer to write `int *p = nullptr;` over `int *p = 0;`. To be consistent with calling `foo(nullptr)` instead of `foo(0)`, because the later causes problems with overloads.

Comment: I don't think there is any syntax difference here since the compiler knows how to compare 0 with (void*)0 , thus it's a matter of preferable choice

Comment: Considering the definition of 'idiomatic' which is "to use, contain, or denote expressions that are natural to a native speaker" I'd say that `if(ptr)` is more idiomatic since its origin is in the very base of `C++` which is `C`.

Comment: If you add to your question "only answers that provide an argument by an objective measure" like by size (would go for "if(p)") or least number of implicit conversions (would go for the other), and if you would not ask for THE best but would just ask for arguments for the different styles, I would vote for reopen because then it is not opinion based.

Comment: Personally, I prefer `if (ptr != nullptr)` (or, in C, `if (ptr != NULL)`, because it's more explicit. Of course both are equivalent to `if (ptr)`; I just find the more explicit forms clearer. Plenty of smart and competent programmers prefer the more terse form `if (ptr)`.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I asked for an objective reason now, is this version better?